# How to get the containing form of an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I need to get a reference to the FORM parent of an INPUT when I only have a reference to that INPUT. Is this possible with JavaScript? Use jQuery if you like.

```
function doSomething(element) {
    //element is input object
    //how to get reference to form?
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
var form = $(element).parents('form:first');

alert($(form).attr("name"));
```

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Native DOM elements that are inputs also have a `form` attribute that points to the form they belong to:

```
var form = element.form;
alert($(form).attr('name'));
```

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp), the `.form` property of input fields is supported by IE 4.0+, Firefox 1.0+, Opera 9.0+, which is even more browsers that jQuery guarantees, so you should stick to this.

If this were a different type of element (not an `<input>`), you could find the closest parent with [`closest`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest):

```
var $form = $(element).closest('form');
alert($form.attr('name'));
```

Also, see this MDN link on the `form` property of `HTMLInputElement`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement#Properties

Comment: Alright this works.. About the form attribute. I just tried it and that also works. But this isn't supported across browsers you're saying?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. I'm just not 100% sure so I don't want to promise anything. I'm looking into it right now...

Comment: Use element.form - it will work on more browsers than jQuery does. It's also one property reference, so will be around a thousand times more efficient than walking up the DOM tree with closest().

Comment: I agree. As I said, I just wasn't initially sure if the form property was extensively implemented in all common browsers. I've edited my answer to more explicitly list this as the better option while I'm leaving closest as a tidbit if this was a different type of element.

Comment: It seems to work also with other input types like select. Good to know.

Comment: What if you have form input groups and you want to add a new input group depending on which inputs have already been completed? I have tried $('form-group input').on('focus', function(){ $(this).closest('form-group') }); without much luck without actually getting the form group tag. Any ideas as to why it won't keep traversing up the node tree?

Comment: `element.form.name` works just fine.

Answer (score 55):

Every input has a `form` property which points to the form the input belongs to, so simply:

```
function doSomething(element) {
  var form = element.form;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
function doSomething(element) {
    var form = $(element).closest("form").get().
    //do something with the form.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use a bit of jQuery and old style javascript - less code

```
$($(this)[0].form)
```

This is a complete reference to the form containing the element

Comment: You're basically saying "make this a jQuery object and then make it not a jQuery object".

Comment: geez, why not just doing `$(this.form)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
function doSomething(element) {
  var form = element.form;
}
```

and in the html, you need to find that element, and add the attribut "form" to connect to that form, please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp
but this form attr **doesn't support IE**, for ie, you need to pass form id directly.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to use `element.attr('form')` instead of `element.form`.

I use Firefox on Fedora 12.

Answer (score 2):

If using jQuery and have a handle to any form element, you need to get(0) the element before  using .form

```
var my_form = $('input[name=first_name]').get(0).form;
```

Answer (score 2):

This example of a Javascript function is called by an event listener to identify the form

```
function submitUpdate(event) {
    trigger_field = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    trigger_form = trigger_field.form;
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more....

```
var _e = $(e.target); // e being the event triggered
var element = _e.parent(); // the element the event was triggered on
console.log("_E " + element.context); // [object HTMLInputElement]
console.log("_E FORM " + element.context.form); // [object HTMLFormElement]
console.log("_E FORM " + element.context.form.id); // form id
```

Answer (score -1):

simply as:

```
alert( $(this.form).attr('name') );
```

Answer (score -2):

would this work? (leaving action blank submits form back to itself too, right?)

```
<form action="">
<select name="memberid" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="1">member 1</option>
<option value="2">member 2</option>
</select>
```

"this" would be the select element, .form would be its parent form.  Right?