# Javascript Form Validation access values

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

If I pass a form to a Javascript validation function, what is the syntax to access the values in the fields if I don't know the form's name?

I pass it in the HTML like so:

```
<form method=...  action=...>
 <input type="text" name="qty-box" value="100" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) addBoxSubmit(this);" />
</form>
```

Now in my javascript function like so:

```
 function addBoxSubmit (myForm) { 
  //how to access the form values none of these methods worked, 
  //I need to know the correct syntax
  //I tried     myform.['qty-box'].value;
  //I tried     myForm['qty-box'].value;
  //I tried     document.myForm.['qty-box'].value;
  //I tried     document.myForm['qty-box'].value;
 }
```

For this application I will have many forms on the page that I want to use with my validation function, essentially each row on a data table is its own form. I can't just access the forms by name because they are dynamically generated serialized names.

Comment: Maybe I'm not passing the form correctly in the html?

Comment: You can set the id of the form to `qty-box` and then `document.getElementById('qty-box')`. Or simply `document.qty-box`, but one problem may be that Javascript does not like the object name to have a - in it, as that is the minus sign in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case is that I'm not passing the form to the validation function, but merely the element on the form. If you have the element though you can access the form given the element with this syntax:

var formName = myElement.form.name;

See: [How to get the form parent of an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991367/how-to-get-the-form-parent-of-an-input)

Comment: `onkeydown` event handler will execute with `this` being the `input` element that receives the key

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a loop in Javascript, and iterate over all forms on the page: `document.forms[i]`. And then check the values on each form.