# Get form & FormData objects from input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

So I want to fire a Javascript function every time a form 'submit' input is clicked, so I can handle the submission in Javascript.

I have the following:

```
$(':submit').click(function(){
    var currentForm = $(this)[0].form;
    event.preventDefault(); //Stop default form submission
    var formData = new FormData(currentForm);

    $.ajax({/*Handle form submission here*/});
});
```

I've tried a few different variations to get the currentForm, but for some reason it's always undefined?

Is this not the correct way to get a `form` object and then convert it to a `FormData` object in Javascript? I've tried several of the solutions on [How to get the form parent of an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991367/how-to-get-the-form-parent-of-an-input), but none are working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to pass the `event`:

```
$(':submit').click(function(event){
   var currentForm = $('form')[0];
   event.preventDefault(); //Stop default form submission
   var formData = new FormData(currentForm);

   $.ajax({/*Handle form submission here*/});
});
```

**UPDATE**

So it appears `$('form')` returns a jQuery object, but an HTML element needs to be passed to `FormData.` `[0]` does that. It is the same as calling `$('form').get(0)`. So use `$('form')[0]`

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your actual code, but if you only have 1 form on the page and `$('form')[0]` works go for it.