# Multiple forms on page, how to get values for all fields when one field changes using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table of data on a page. Each row contains a form with 3 fields.

I have some jquery code that successfully recognizes that a field has changed and gets that field's value, but I don't know how to get the other fields' values in that same form.

Comment: add some html and any code you have/have tried

Comment: Thanks Sam, I think I found the solution. I spent all day looking at this and then when I post my question, I find the Answer! Every form element has a form attribute that connects you back to the parent form. There is an example here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991367/how-to-get-the-form-parent-of-an-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the change-event of the field element that was changed, and registered the change-callback with jQuery.

In the callback, `this` is the changed input field (as a normal DOM element). You can then use `jQuery(this).closest('form')` to get the form that field belongs to.

To read the formdata, e.g. in order to send it in an AJAX call, you can use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.