# Django - a form input field doesn't get posted

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, forms

I have a table. One of the columns is a checkbox column, and I want the form to be submitted whenever a checkbox's "checked" attribute is changed.

I've also added an hidden input field to the form, so I can tell what checkbox has changed.

I did manage to get the form to submit when a checkbox status is changed (with JQuery), but for some reason the hidden input field is not posted along.

The only thing in `request.POST` in the view is the csrf token.

```
<table class="bordered striped centered responsive-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="season">Season</th>
                    <th data-field="episode">Episode</th>
                    <th data-field="title">Title</th>
                    <th data-field="date">Air Date</th>
                    <th data-field="watched">Watched</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for episode in episodes %}
                  <tr>
                      <td>{{ episode.season }}</td>
                      <td>{{ episode.number }}</td>
                      <td>{{ episode.title }}</td>
                      <td>{{ episode.date }}</td>
                      <td><form id='episodes' action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" id="episode_title" value="{{ episode.title }}"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ episode.title }}" {% if episode.watched %}checked="checked" {% endif %}/>
                            <label for="{{ episode.title }}"></label>
                          </form>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#episodes").on("change", "input:checkbox", function(){
        $("#episodes").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT** I Tried @bfrederi 's suggestion. Didn't change much. The form is posted but only with the csrf token.

```
<td><form id='episodes-{{ episode.title }}' action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" id="episode_title" value="{{ episode.title }}"/>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="episode-check" id="{{ episode.title }}" {% if episode.watched %}checked="checked" {% endif %}/>
                        <label for="{{ episode.title }}"></label>
                      </form></td>

.
.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".episode-check").change(function() {
        this.closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I went with a totally different approach that works for me, posting as an answer for future generations :)

What I did was to create a new url to post to, instead of posting to the same url.
Then I simply provide more parameters to the post function in my view.

So the 2 urls for the same view:

```
url(r'^show/(?P<show_name>.+)/episodes', ShowDetail.as_view(), name='show-detail'),
url(r'^show/(?P<show_name>.+)-(?P<episode_season>\d+)-(?P<episode_number>\d+)',
    ShowDetail.as_view(), name='show-detail-update')
```

Then on the page I simply post to the newly created url:

```
<td><form id='episodes-{{ episode.title }}' action="{% url 'shows_app:show-detail-update' show_name episode.season episode.number %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="checkbox" class="episode-check" id="{{ episode.title }}" {% if episode.watched %}checked="checked" {% endif %}/>
                            <label for="{{ episode.title }}"></label>
     </form>
</td>
```

And the view itself:

```
class ShowDetail(View):
    def get(self, request, show_name):
        # handling the get request

    def post(self, request, show_name, episode_season, episode_number):
        # handling the post request
        # referring the user the the same page
        return self.get(request, show_name)
```

It still feels like a bit of a hack, but it works.

If anyone has a better suggestion I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: This is just a guess, but looking at the differences in your templates it could have been that you didn't specify an **action** in your original template (depending on your browser). A good practice is to always specify a relative/absolute url in the **action** (like you did in this answer).

Comment: Or, perhaps more likely, it could be how Django received your multipart form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#testing-for-multipart-forms

Answer (score 1):

**First**, you have created multiple forms with the same id:

```
<form id='episodes' action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You can forgo form ids entirely and use a JQuery [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="episode-check" {% if episode.watched %}checked="checked" {% endif %}/>
```

and

```
$(".episode-check").change(function() {
    this.closest('form').submit();
}
```

...to access the parent form element [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/991371/264567). Then call submit on the correct form (you should still have unique ids if you are giving your forms id's).

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem of multiple forms with the same ID. However, if I would give each one a different ID, which ID would the JQuery need to use for submitting and listening for changes?

Comment: You would want to change your selector to use classes instead of ids for the onChange. Then access the parent form as explained in the link I provided.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but `request.POST` still contains only the csrf token. I've updated by question with the current code.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It appeared to be your onChange JQuery.

Comment: Still nothing is posted except for the csrf token :/

Comment: Here is a working JSFiddle of what you're attempting: https://jsfiddle.net/85ryf1v2/1/ I would also suggest making the id on your hidden field unique. `<input type="hidden" id="{{episode.id}}" value="{{ episode.title }}"/>`

Comment: You can also run the resulting HTML of your page through an [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to attempt to find issues in your html that might be causing the bad form submission.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle to actually submit the form: https://jsfiddle.net/85ryf1v2/2/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) to understand how html elements are processed and passed through the request object.