# How to get the form parent of an input with jquery 1.8?

Tags: jquery

This is a duplicate of this question:

- [How to get the form parent of an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991367/how-to-get-the-form-parent-of-an-input)

... but time moved on. I think the accepted answer is not valid any more.

I want to submit the form of the checkbox, if the checkbox was changed.

```
$(document).on("change", "#my_checkbox_input", function() {
    $(this).???
});
```

What should `???` look like with jquery version >= 1.8?

Comment: can you show your HTML so that we come to know what exactly you want to do

Comment: @Anant I want to keep the question as simple as possible. I don't think HTML is needed here. If your comment gets more then two upvotes, then I am wrong and I will provide html.

Comment: if you need to grab the `<form>` element which is acting as a container to your checkboxes then I believe `$(this).closest('form')` should work. Why do you feel that it will not work with  jquery version >= 1.8?

Comment: @vijayP You ask why I think something does not work with  jquery version >= 1.8? .... This was just added to be more precise. I don't need to support older version.

Comment: @guettli I see you've added a bounty on the question. Is there something more specific you need to know which my answer does not cover?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am not an JS expert .. I see two ways to access the relevant form: via dom (method closest()) or via the attribute of the current element. I am unsure up to now. I want to know what other people think.

Comment: Both of those approaches are the same logic, just one uses jQuery the other native JS. If you've already included jQuery in the page you may as well use that to maintain consistency. From the sounds of it you may be over-analysing the solution. There are lots of way to do DOM traversal, generally speaking you can't go too far wrong: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `this` keyword that refer in the event context to the object of the current changed element, then just use `this.form` to get the parent form where the current element wrapped, then call the `submit()` method if you want to submit it like  like :

```
$(document).on("change", "#my_checkbox_input", function() {
    this.form.submit();
});
```

Or also by converting the form to jQuery object first :

```
$(document).on("change", "#my_checkbox_input", function() {
    $(this.form).submit();
});
```

And you could always use the jQuery methods `.parents()` or `.closest()` to get the parent element, in this case use the jQuery object `$(this)` that refer to the current element then specify the parent node name (`form`), like :

```
$(document).on("change", "#my_checkbox_input", function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

**NOTE :** `.closest()` is more efficient than `.parents()` in term of speed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Image you teach a newcomer JS. What would you suggest him to use (like "if unsure take ...")? And why would you suggest this?

Comment: I've added a brief explanation... take a look please.

Comment: @ZakariaArcharki thank you for adding an explanation. I will use `$(this.form).submit();` in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `closest()` to find the parent `form` element, then call `submit()` on it:

```
$(document).on("change", "#my_checkbox_input", function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Also note that `closest()` has been available since jQuery 1.3, so the version makes very little difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).parent()
```

Or:

```
$(this).parent().find('#parent_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work in this situation, but please note that others have answered with the same syntax above.

```
$(document).on("change", "#my_checkbox_input", function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    // do whatever you want with the form as `form` 
});
```

The `.closest()` method searches through elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and returns the closest one matching the passed query.  In this case we were looking for a form, so it will return the form you are looking for.