# Post login data to site with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to write a small script that upon running it should fill some data in a html site that are already given. So for example lets say the site is the [stackoverflow logn page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) and I need to fill my username and password.

Knowing that for the username we have:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="30" maxlength="100" placeholder="you@example.org">
```

password:

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="********">
```

and data:

```
data = {username:"user", password:"pass"};
```

our js should be something like below (correct?):

```
document.getElementById("email").value=data.username; 
document.getElementById("password").value=data.password;
```

What I dont really understand is how to "post" that into the site and then hit the login button.(ajax?) Generally how to bring it together and make it a running script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

having embedded you input filed in an HTML form with `id="myForm"`

Comment: Hmm I kinda understand what you might but still am not sure how to get the site's form and do it. Am pretty good with c/nodejs but have used very little js/html so with little to none explanation it doesnt really help me much. Thanks for the answer though! :)

Comment: I understand how to do it with my form (if I create one), am struggling doing it with a site's form though

Comment: May be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991367/how-to-get-the-form-parent-of-an-input

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the login page domain, you could create a obscured login page, which sets login values to local storage then, loads the "regular" login page, which looks for and reads the local storage and logs in.

Here is a sample login page.

user= **test**
password= **testpw**

[test login page](http://shawnanderson.net/stack/login.html)

and here is the "secret" login page, where you send the credentials via GET like this:
http://shawnanderson.net/stack/secretlogin.html?userID=test&userPW=testpw

[secret login page](http://shawnanderson.net/stack/secretlogin.html?userID=test&userPW=testpw)

Otherwise, you could load the login page in an iframe and populate the login fields from there.

[iframe example](http://shawnanderson.net/stack/iframe.html)

Comment: The links you have provided do not serve much purpose. I mean you coulda remove them and everything would still come across the same.

Comment: Okay I understand how I would have done it if it was my website, but how do I post the credentials from my pc to an online form. The iframe method seemed to be the most simple. Btw nice work wtih the P90 ;)

Comment: So you want to click a link on your desktop or something and log into a website? If you can't put  files on the webserver then you'll need another approach. I'm not an expert, but this guy did what you want using a scripting language called autohotkey.

https://jszapp.com/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-automatically-logs-in-to-any-website